# How to save both best and latest model in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use `Keras Model` checkpoint callback to save best model as well as latest model. Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve creating a new `ModelCheckpoint` class and modifying the `on_epoch_end` function?

The checkpointer I currently use is:

```py
checkpter = keras.callbacks
    .ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_dir + 'checkpt_{epoch:02d} + _.hdf5', monitor='val_loss',
                     verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode='auto',
                     period=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If by latest model you mean the model after the final epoch, you can just simply leave the Checkpoint function unchanged and save your final result.

After you fit the model add this line of code:

```
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

The checkpoint function will save the best model, and after you finish training, the model will save one final time, regardless of the result.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new `callback` function to save models at each epoch.

```
class saveLatesModel(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, modelSaveLocation='', modelName=''):
        super(keras.callbacks.Callback, self).__init__()
        self.modelSaveLocation = '..'
        self.modelName = '..'

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.model.save(self.modelSaveLocation+self.modelName+'.hdf5', overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I could add this along with other callbacks.